# Overpopulation novel about a man ripped to pieces by a starving mob, and state-registered prostitutes

Tags: story-identification, novel

Definitely published no later than 1974, set in the future on Earth.

I only remember the final scene. A man visits his ex-wife, an official state-registered prostitute whom anyone can legally use. I remember a sentence, "you would never have guessed she was thirty".

After seeing her he's trapped in a room or cell and a starving mob is outside and he's literally ripped to pieces as he tries to escape. It's written in the third person.

Comment: HI there. That's some info already, but please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in. As for the mail - that's not really the way things are done here, answers will be posted as answers... But we do have some prominent story-ID answerers, so make sure to keep an eye on that question! :)

Comment: https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/573724/

Comment: God! I remember that question over in Chronicles, I actually spent over five hours one sleepless night scrolling through old SF book sites until I finally identified it!..... The compulsion really takes over sometimes

Comment: @DannyMcG, no reason you can't submit a more comprehensive answer here, too. I just didn't want to leave this one in the unanswered queue.

Comment: Nah, it's okay, there's enough detail already here to clearly identify the book

Answer (score 3):

Per the thread cited by Valorum above in a comment, this story was identified as *[Waters of Death](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?21904)* (1967) by Irving A. Greenfield.

An [online review](http://glorioustrash.blogspot.com/2018/04/waters-of-death.html) notes some of the same details as mentioned by the OP:

> There isn’t even any regret on Wilde’s part when his wife announces
> she’s to become a government whore of sorts at the local “sex
> center”...

and

> ...[T]he rioters, now that the sea crops have all been destroyed, have
> turned to cannibalism, and Wilde, thinking he’s being freed from
> prison by a group of rioters, discovers instead that they’ve come here
> to *eat him*.